# Javascript JSON Parsing from ViewModel in MVC "Unexpected Token &"

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, model-view-controller, viewmodel

There are a lot of questions hanging around on this of which I've already tried all the answers I can find. I am brand new to Javascript/JSON and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going wrong here.

So, in my controller I have this:

```
var mapVM = new MapVM();
var vehicleVM = Mapper.Map<List<Vehicle>, List<VehicleVM>>(vehicles).ToList());
//Automapper here ^

var jsonVehicleVM = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vehicleVM);

mapVM.Vehicles = jsonVehicleVM;

//At this point mapVM.Vehicles is perfect JSON and displays in Visual Studio in JSON View
return View(mapVM);
```

In the view, I have this:

```
var jsonString = @Model.Vehicles;
var vehicles = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

But it looks like:

```
var jsonString = [{&quot;ShortReg&quot;:&quot;*Android Phone&quot;,&quot;Reg&quot;:&quot;*Android - Kate (Galaxy S3)&quot;,&quot;LatestLoca.......... ETC
```

Now, I'm guessing it's throwing a fit because of those " bits in there.

I've tried the whole .replace() thing, didn't work. I am frustrated because I'd rather be able to run a loop in javascript on the items than having to write @: for every new line of C# code I'm looping through if I want it to output to the page.

Comment: Try `var jsonString = @Html.Raw(Model.Vehicles);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As devqon suggested:

```
var jsonString = @Html.Raw(Model.Vehicles);
```